# Wired internet not working with an Intel 82579LM NIC

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, internet-connection

I have been searching all day to no avail. I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 as dual boot on a dell optiplex 990, which has a Intel 82579LM NIC. I have it wired up via ethernet to my college network, and it says it is connected to the wired network, yet I have not internet and cannot ping anything. Below I have included some basic checks (pretty much the limit of my knowledge on this subject). It is worth noting that when running windows (it is dual booted) the internet works fine so NIC is fine and so is the ethernet cable itself. I have also downloaded the driver for the NIC from intel and installed on the machine in ubuntu (driver downloaded from [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=15817&ProdId=3299&lang=eng&OSVersion=Linux*&DownloadType=Drivers))

I have run the following commands:
**ifconfig:**

```
aly@neon:~/Downloads/e1000e-2.1.4/src$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:1c:5e:2a:06  
          inet6 addr: 2001:630:12:1082:92b1:1cff:fe5e:2a06/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:630:12:1075:92b1:1cff:fe5e:2a06/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::92b1:1cff:fe5e:2a06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:891800 (891.8 KB)  TX bytes:36150 (36.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e1500000-e1520000 

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:1c:5e:2a:06  
          inet addr:169.254.3.202  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e1500000-e1520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:137020 (137.0 KB)  TX bytes:137020 (137.0 KB)
```

**lspci**

```
 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
```

**ping 8.8.8.8**

```
aly@neon:~/Downloads/e1000e-2.1.4/src$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.3.202 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.3.202 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.3.202 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.3.202 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.3.202 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.3.202 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
```

And here is a screenshot of the connection information (when connected to the wired network), it seems odd as there is no ipv4 addr

[image]

Comment: Hey Ali, is your problem still existant? If no, what have you done to get rid of it?

Comment: @qbi Problem was fixed by sys admins, they just moved me onto a different network. I will close question as I doubt anyone will benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:avahi down
```

and then try connecting again.

Comment: gives me the error SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: check your `ifconfig` output again and if there are more than one `eth0` connections, turn off the second one using the above command.

Comment: ifconfig shows just eth0 and lo

Comment: it has now magically started working. It has done this once before but then just dies out again :s

Comment: well, at any point of time you should have only one `eth0`, if it's the case the connection should work.

Comment: last night I also only had one eth0, but no such luck :s

Comment: strange machine, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I note:

> SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address

That suggests there are settings in /etc/network/interfaces that are interfering and conflicting with Network Manager. Please check:

```
    sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

The file should conatin nothing more than:

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Restart NM:

```
    sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now does it connect? If not, please check for any settings in Network Manager. For instance, if you've asked for a static address of 192.168.1.203 and the college network uses 192.168.*55*.0 etc., you won't connect. Remove any extra settings in NM.