# Ethernet problem in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ethernet, 13.04

Can't wait till raring officially release, I decided to use daily-image of it.

However, my ethernet is not working. cannot be selected and activated to retrieve DHCP from my LAN.

It was working when I bootup my ubuntu with LAN cable attached, but to day I rebooted many times with attached cable the ethernet still not working.

WLAN is working just fine.

Comment: Hi Husni, can you provide the Network card model?

Comment: Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network

Comment: did you try http://askubuntu.com/questions/201441/wired-internet-not-working-with-an-intel-82579lm-nic

Answer (score 3):

Somehow it went up (the Ethernet picking up the DHCP on my LAN) after I plug the laptop charger/adapter as the battery ran out

Comment: I have to say that I read your answer because I was having the same problem and I was laughing really hard because of the solution that you gave.But once I connected the laptop to the charger the wired connection worked and I couldn't believe my eyes.This is like the weirdest bug I have ever seen in my life.Anyway thanks for your help! :))

Comment: I've got the same problem and filled a launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/1174184

Answer (score 1):

There's a current [bug report on LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1112652) and the latest news is that the fix is due with the 3.8.13 kernel updates.

I'm using 13.04 on a Dell Latitude e6430u with the same problem (Intel NIC).

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue. Using Paul's supplied link to the bug I've used the workaround that is mentioned there - simply type this into the command line:

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control
```

Comment: It really works :)